# WAMP Internal Server Error

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I downloaded & installed WAMP. Imported my database in phpMyAdmin and tried launching the website via my browser: `http://localhost/myWebsite/index.php`

I get the following error message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

**Update** I checked the logs and all I see as an error is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2012:14:40:14 +0000] "GET /myWebsite/index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 528
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your error log update and the error message that you are getting, it's an [HTTP Error 500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) which indicates that the server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request..

You need to check your code and any *.htaccess* files residing on your server..

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the the apache rewrite module loaded.

go to `wamp_manager -> apache -> modules` and look for `rewrite_module` in the list.

If it does not have a TICK beside it click it. Apache will be bounced ( stop, start ). Try again.

The `rewite` engine will not work without the required module loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, locate your server logs, they should provide some details.

Comment: That's not getting very far , try enabling mod rewrite  uncomment #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in your htaccess file

Comment: There's billions of htaccess files within the www folder. Can you please clarify which one.

Comment: Sorry man, early, i meant httpd.conf, should be where wamp installs apache.

Comment: Ok. I have the file open. Can you please clearly specify again what I need to do? Your post earlier doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes of course, you should see a line in there that says: #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so , just remove the #